# Weird slider behaviour in Unity (Handle disappearing)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, slider

So I have a slider in UI which is used to display a video progress bar. For this reason I have extended the regular `Slider` class to also have a property to check if it's being used (so the user can still drag the handle which is automatically updated). This is the class:

```
public class VideoSlider : Slider
{
    public bool IsUsed { get; private set; }
    public void SilentSet(float value)
    {
        Set(value, false);
    }

    public override void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        base.OnPointerDown(eventData);
        IsUsed = true;
    }

    public override void OnPointerUp(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        base.OnPointerUp(eventData);
        IsUsed = false;
    }
}
```

Now, in the `Update` function of the video control script, I'm updating the slider based on video time:

```
public void Update()
{
        var pos = (float)ModuleManager.instance.GetVideoPosition();
        if (!videoSlider.IsUsed)
            videoSlider.SilentSet(pos);
}
```

And here's where the problem occurs: When I do that, the slider handle disappears. I've checked `ModuleManager.instance.GetVideoPosition` multiple times to make sure it returns a value between 0 and 1 (which are the min and max of my slider) but as soon as I use the value returned from that function the handle is gone. If I use literally any other value (static value, `Time.time`, etc) the slider works as expected and moves forward at a steady pace while still allowing the user to drag it around but for some reason as soon as I use the value returned by that function it freaks out.
Am I just out of luck on this one?

Comment: Nothing in your code looks problematic to me.  Can we see the GetVideoPosition method?

Comment: It's just ```return player.time / player.length;``` where ``player`` is a ``VideoPlayer``

Comment: And if you log the value of pos before you call SilentSet, it's always giving you a suitable value?

Comment: Yep, it's always a value between 0 and 1, I made sure with various logs and asserts.

Comment: Okay. This was bugging me so I set up a project that mirrors your project.  And I can't replicate the behaviour that you're describing.  It works as expected for me.  Can you add a screenshot of the inspector for your Slider gameobject?

Comment: It seems that the player reported 0 as video length when the video wasnt prepared yet which seemed to cause the issue (division by 0 obviously). But the resulting value of the division was always in the appropriate range and there were no exceptions which is kind of weird.

Comment: Yeah, that's a tricky one. Nice find. Perhaps you should add that as an answer to help anyone who searches for a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the player reported 0 as video length when the video wasn't prepared yet which seemed to cause the issue (division by 0 obviously). But the resulting value of the division was always in the appropriate range and there were no exceptions which is kind of weird.